# Theorem 4, Section 2.3 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation, independence

> Let $V$ be a vector space which is spanned by a finite set of vectors $\beta_1,…,\beta_m$. Then any independent set of vectors in $V$ is finite and contains no more than $m$ elements.

**Question:** **(1)** How does interchanging of sum work, $\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^m (A_{ij}x_j)\beta_i= \sum_{i=1}^m (\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}x_j)\beta_i$? **(2)** I don’t understand following sentence in the proof: “since $n\gt m$, theorem 6 of chapter 1 implies that there exists scalars $x_1,…,x_n$ not all $0$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}x_j=0$, $1\leq i\leq m$“. Mainly because I haven’t yet studied matrix theory. Is it absolutely necessary to do matrix theory(chapter 1 of Hoffman’s) before chapter 2? I’m also dodging examples involving matrix theory. Can we prove question(2) without using any matrix theory?

Comment: The order of summations can ALWAYS be interchanged in case of finite summation . Notw that you are writing as an iterated summation but in general $\sum_{x,y}f(x,y)$ is not an iterated summation. But yes , if the interchange of summation is valid( in case the range of x and y is finite or that the summand is positive , then by Fubini's Theorem)  you can evaluate the summations in an iterated manner. That is first compute the sum over $j$ treating $i$ as a constant and then sum over $i$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron thank you for answering Que(1).

Comment: Matrix theory is equivalent to general theory because all finite dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ via change of basis. Indeed, to start out doing linear algebra, you have to prove some things about $\mathbb{R}^n$ first.

Comment: For finite summations you do not need to invoke Fubini to justify exchanging the order of summation. It follows because addition is commutative and associative, and you've been using those facts since grade school. They didn't go away because you used $\sum$ notation instead of a string of $+$s.

Comment: There is a proof which don’t use matrix theory. See theorem 6 section 4.2 of Hungerford’s abstract algebra (page no. $185$).